# Is there anything like the Enterprise Library Patterns & Practices for console applications?

Tags: c#, exception, console-application, enterprise-library

Is there anything like the [Enterprise Library Patterns & Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx) for use in console applications? I'm specifically looking for something to use for logging / email notification on exceptions instead of calling a `SendExceptionMail` function on every `catch` block.

Comment: What's wrong with the Enterprise Library for Console Applications?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I was under the impression that it only worked with web applications?

Comment: I'm not sure about Web Applications, but it works quite well with Console or Windows Apps.

Comment: Didn't realize that, will have to investigate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) for this sort of thing, I generally configure the executable with multiple appenders and dispense with `Console.Write()` altogether. I generally have (at least) a

- `ColoredConsoleAppender` or `ConsoleAppender` to log to the console
- `RollingFileAppender` to create a log file.

Just add an `SmtpAppender` to send events via email. Add other appenders to log to the Windows event log or a SQL database as needed.

See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html for some config examples.

As an aside...why do you need multiple `catch` blocks? You shouldn't be `catch`-ing anything unless you're actually *handling* the exception — though there are some exceptions: I'd recommend catching, logging and continuing exceptions at the points at which process or machine boundaries are crossed.

Instead, let exceptions bubble up. Have a single `catch` in `Main()` that logs the exceptions. Much simpler.

Comment: +1 - You shouldn't need an email unless an unexpected error occurs (unless you want emails for everyday occurrences). And unexpected errors shouldn't occur. So, you probably only need to generate emails inside one catch block.